# Having troubles with making a rig work. (Jaw face and neck seem to move incorrectly)

Tags: rigging, bones, weight-painting

Sigh, I have been working on this model over and over again. And i had to trash the old on and make this new one. But everything I try to make this model work correctly fails. the Tentacles work, the legs work. but the face doesn't work. I have tried weight painting and everything, and this dog will not move the way I want him too.

Please someone, anyone, help me. I don't know what I am doing wrong. I have tried everything.  I even tried manually weight painting every single bone. but there is something about the dog that just wont work.

His jaw and face and neck is thru problem, the move so awkwardly, shrinking and growing with the rotation, or noting in a way that is not even close to how I move it when I use any of the tools.

https://pasteall.org/media/b/4/b4871f2e74f656e7a71d6e58ec80bd52.blend

Answer (score 2):

You have a weight painting problem.

Switch to the model and enter edit mode.  Select one of the vertices in the jaw. Open the side panel and switch to the item tab.  Open the Vertex Weights tab and have a look:

[image: One of the jaw vertices' vertex groups]

The lower jaw is `spine.017` but you're also having the vertices influenced by the upper jaw `spine.014`.

Select all of the vertices in the lower jaw.  Go to the Object Data Properties and find `spine.014`.  Select it.  Click remove.  Then Next select `spine.017`, make sure Weight is set to 1.0 and click assign.

[image: Spine.014 selected]

You have a similar problem with the upper jaw, but with the bones reversed.

After that you'll have to experiment and see what other vertices are assigned to multiple groups.  Some should be, as some vertices need to move under the influence of two or more different bones, but many should not.

Comment: A full 12 hours of trying and that didnt work. Nothing seems to work.

Comment: It worked when I tried it on the file in your question.  What doesn't work for you?

Comment: It just doesn't work. I did what you said, and the head still behaves very wrong. It twists to the left or right upon up and down rotation. I went  vert by vert all over this thing body. I even tried unparenting and starting over and it still just moves incorrectly..

Comment: I just tried again, and the model now just doesnt work at all. Now the whole thing crumples like paper im so bad at this

Comment: You're not bad at it. It's just a hard thing to do.  Weight painting is one of the hardest parts of rigging to get right.  Maybe practice on simpler models until you get a feeling for what you're doing.  I started out practicing on a sub divided cube with only three bones in the armature.  Maybe [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LPYs3pZEzPY) will help.

Comment: So give up... cool

Comment: I didn't say "give up". I said "work up to it".  Practice on simpler things and move on to more complex things until you're comfortable enough to do this one.